# XmlTextReader for json?

Tags: asp.net, json, .net-4.0, xmltextreader

Is there something that is *similar* to XmlTextReader in terms of performance, but using JSON instead?

I have the choice between parsing data in XML or parsing the same data in JSON. I'd like to use JSON because I figure I could save a bit of bandwidth but I'd like to keep the performance of XmlTextReader. In other words, how do I stream JSON data? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) project contains a `JsonTextReader` class that might be what you are looking for. Didn't use it myself though, so I can't give any specifics.